# NSOperationQueue methods parameter are becoming empty

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, nsoperationqueue, nsoperation

I am having problem with `NSOperationQueue`, if I am adding the same operation for 200 times method is behaving as expected. 
But if I increase the for loop to 500 times, parameter are becoming empty when queue will start executing the task. Below is the code snippet.

```
- (void)someMethod:(char *)param1 {
    NSBlockOperation *theOp = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock: ^{
        // use this paramter and do something
    }];
    [[MyQueueService sharedMyQueueService] operationQueue] addOperation:theOp];
}
```

This is how I am invoking the above method

```
for (int index = 1; index < 500; index++) {
    MyClass *classInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    NSString *parm1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", index];
    [classInstance someMethod:(char *)[string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
```

Here is becoming empty i.e "", if i run the same method for 500 time, due to this I am unable to perform other operation. Please help me regarding this.

Comment: By the way, even if you were programming in C and wanted to use `char *` pointers, you should be using `const char *` pointers unless you're really mutating the buffer it points to. And if you were doing that, you should copy the contents of the `const char *` pointer to a `char *` buffer of your own. But you should never cast a `const char *` pointer to a `char *` pointer. This is likely entirely moot, as you are writing Objective-C code, not C, and probably shouldn't be passing around `char *` pointers at all (esp in asynchronous code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with `NSOperationQueue`. The issue is the use of `char *`. As the [documentation for `cStringUsingEncoding` says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1408489-cstringusingencoding?language=objc):

> The returned C string is guaranteed to be valid only until either the receiver is freed, or until the current memory is emptied, whichever occurs first. You should copy the C string or use `getCString:maxLength:encoding:` if it needs to store the C string beyond this time.

Bottom line, simple C pointers like `char *` do not participate in (automatic) reference counting. Your code is using dangling pointers to unmanaged buffer pointers. This is exceedingly dangerous and when not done properly (as in this case), will lead to undefined behavior. The resulting behavior is dictated whether the memory in question happened to be reused for other purposes in the intervening time, which can lead to unpredictable behavior that changes based upon completely unrelated factors (e.g. the loop count or whatever).

You should try running your app with the "address sanitizer" turned on (found in the scheme settings under the "run" settings, on the diagnostics tab) and it will likely report some of these issues. E.g. when I ran your code with address sanitizer, it reported:

> ==15249==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x60300003a458 at pc 0x00010ba3bde6 bp 0x70000e837880 sp 0x70000e837028

For more information, see [Address Sanitizer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/code_diagnostics/address_sanitizer) or its [introductory video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/413/).

The easiest solution is going to be to eliminate the `char *` and instead use the `int` index value or use an object, such as `NSString *`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It was really helpful